# Filtering in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to take the data from the JSON file ([link to file](http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2)).
   If I have to sort by the name or by the year of release, how to filter 
   the contents in that 2D array.

Can anyone please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to get your api response, and than sort using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Sort by `Year`:

```js
$.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2", (result) => {
    result.Search.sort((a, b, by) => {
        return a.Year < b.Year ? -1 : a.Year > b.Year ? 1 : 0;
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying!that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can extend original [Yosvel Quintero answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37509286/3708596) to accept type of sorting:

```js
function sort(type) {
    $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2", ({ Search }) => {   
        Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
        console.log(Search);
    });
}
sort('Year');
sort('Title');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks!!that was very clear

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sort(type) {
    $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2", ({ Search }) => {   
        Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
        console.log(Search);
    });
}
sort('Year');
sort('Title');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function sort(type) {
    $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2", ({ Search }) => {   
        Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
        console.log(Search);
    });
}
sort('Year');
sort('Title');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```